# docker has volume permission but docker-compose doesn't

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-ebs, docker-compose

I have installed Docker on an Amazon Linux server and given it permissions with `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`. When I start my Jenkins docker containers (which have the home directories on an EBS mounted volume, mounted at `/var/lib/docker/volumes`) from the command line;

```
docker run -d \
--restart=always \
--name=jenkins-core \
--hostname=jenkins-core \
-p 8080:8080 \
-p 50000:50000 \
--env JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/core" \
-v jenkins-core:/var/jenkins_home \
jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Everything works fine. However when I try to start it from `docker-compose up -d` or `sudo docker-compose up -d` I get;

```
touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?
```

and the docker containers go into a boot loop trying to restart. I cannot figure out why the permissions are wrong on `docker-compose` but fine on `docker`.

I have tried `sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /usr/local/bin/docker-compose` but it didn't work. I installed `docker-compose` from here; https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

here is the `docker-compose.yml` there is also a `.env` file for the variables (not attached)

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  jenkins-core:
    image:           jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name:  jenkins-core
    restart:         always
    ports:
      - ${JENKINS_CORE_HOST_PORT_8080}:${JENKINS_PORT_8080}
      - ${JENKINS_CORE_HOST_PORT_50000}:${JENKINS_PORT_50000}
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS=--prefix=${JENKINS_CORE_PREFIX}
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=${TZ}
    volumes:
      - ${JENKINS_CORE_HOME_DIR}:/var/jenkins_home
  jenkins-integrations:
    image:           jenkins/jenkins:lts
    container_name:  jenkins-integrations
    restart:         always
    ports:
      - ${JENKINS_INTEGRATIONS_HOST_PORT_8080}:${JENKINS_PORT_8080}
      - ${JENKINS_INTEGRATIONS_HOST_PORT_50000}:${JENKINS_PORT_50000}
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS=--prefix=${JENKINS_INTEGRATIONS_PREFIX}
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=${TZ}
    volumes:
      - ${JENKINS_INTEGRATIONS_HOME_DIR}:/var/jenkins_home
  portainer:
    image:           portainer/portainer
    container_name:  portainer
    restart:         always
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
    ports:
      - ${PORTAINER_PORT_9000}:9000
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ${DOCKERCONFDIR}/portainer:/data
    command:         -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
  watchtower:
    image:           v2tec/watchtower
    container_name:  watchtower
    restart:         always
    environment:
      - TZ=${TZ}
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command:         --schedule 0 0 4 * * * --cleanup
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md under Usage. It says `NOTE: Avoid using a bind mount from a folder on the host machine into /var/jenkins_home, as this might result in file permission issues (the user used inside the container might not have rights to the folder on the host machine)...`

So the reason why your `docker run` works is because of `-v jenkins-core:/var/jenkins_home` where `jenkins-core` is a docker volume. In the compose however you use a bind mount to some folder on the host.

Comment: How do I get around this?

Comment: You can change JENKINS_INTEGRATIONS_HOME_DIR and JENKINS_CORE_HOME_DIR to be a one word like jenkinsintegrationdata and docker will create a volume for you in /var/lib/docker/volumes.

Comment: Cool, I'll try that. I find volumes and bind mounts confusing so far. Do you know any good resources to study this further?

Comment: I only use these two for reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes and https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ but I don't know if they provide a good overview since they go into details very quickly